# Error Coming back from DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

```
int monthCount = GetMonthCount(comp.PaymentFrequency);
int day = comp.MaturityDate.GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.Today).Day;
DateTime countFrom = comp.EffectiveDate.GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.Today);

return new DateTime(countFrom.Year, countFrom.Month, day).AddMonths(monthCount);
```

Year, Month, and day parameters describe an unrepresentable datetime? Why?

Comment: What is the error that's coming back?

Comment: The text underneath the code is the error.

Comment: You can replace `x.GetValueOrDefault(y)` with `(x ?? y)`.

Comment: What are the values you that get passed to `DateTime`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If MaturityDate is `1/31/2011` and EffectiveDate is `2/28/2011`, your code will try to create a non-existent date.

Comment: february is always fun with DateTime ;)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this approach will help:

If you want **to get the date that is one month from a specified date**, use `AddMonths`:

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Parse("1/31/2011");
DateTime endDate = startDate.AddMonths(1);
```

Here, `endDate = 2/28/2011.`